# One account shared by multiple sites

Tags: 7

I have two different domain names, e.g. www.exampleA.com and www.exampleB.com.

exampleA.com contain all the reading material.

exampleB.com contain practices or quiz.

Although they are installed at the same server, but different drupal sites.

Recently, I receive an instruction. User need to access both website by using same account ID and password. Once they login, they can read material and take quiz too. However, both domain name are still different due to two different company.

I had installed domain access module successfully, but it cant access to another website due the permission denied. It looks like they need me to point both websites to one drupal site. (or actually dun need?)

Any advice what should I do?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I had changed my question. Any comment?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways.

1. Single Sign On (SSO) (Please read https://www.drupal.org/node/2402397): Bit harder to setup but gives you full control and you can have separate drupal installation for each sites.
2. [domain_access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain): With domain access module, you will need to point both those domain to same drupal installation. Once you setup this module, you will see a checkbox in node add form to publish this content to (This is how the content will be displayed on each site). You can then edit your user account to have access to both sites and can login to both sites using same login details.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks. I had successfully install (CAS) suggested from SSO. However, I not too sure how to configure. Any advice?

Comment: At exampleA.com I enable CAS Server module and I key in exampleB.com at Whitelist text field. At exampleB.com I enable CAS module. Am I configure wrongly?